# Adding PageSpeed Module to installed nginx

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, mod-pagespeed

I like to add the Google PageSpeed Module to my nginx webserver on Ubuntu.

This link gives a simple overview https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/build_ngx_pagespeed_from_source?hl=de but it only covers the case when you install nginx from scratch.

I already have nginx installed, and when I type the following command line inside my /var/lib/nginx folder I get a "No such file" error:

```
./configure --add-module=$HOME/ngx_pagespeed-release-1.7.30.4-beta
```

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet at this issue is to build Nginx from scratch.

Save your nginx config files before to a safe place and then do, assuming you are in Debian:

```
sudo dpkg -r nginx
```

If you are in Debian :  `sudo apt-get install build-essential zlib1g-dev libpcre3-dev`

Just make sure you remove Nginx and get the needed libs to build Nginx from source if not in Debian.

The libs and tools are :

```
gcc-c++ pcre zlib make wget
```

This next part is system independent.

Get the latest Nginx version :

```
cd /usr/src/
sudo wget http://nginx.org/download/nginx-1.7.6.tar.gz
sudo  tar xvfvz nginx-1.7.6.tar.gz
cd /usr/src/nginx-1.7.6
```

Get the latest pagespeed source:

```
sudo wget https://github.com/pagespeed/ngx_pagespeed/archive/v1.9.32.1-beta.zip
```

Unpack first the module :

```
sudo unzip v1.9.32.1-beta.zip

cd ngx_pagespeed-1.9.32.1-beta
```

Wget the PSOL libs inside the module dir and unpack them there:

```
sudo wget wget https://dl.google.com/dl/page-speed/psol/1.9.32.1.tar.gz
sudo  tar xvfvz 1.9.32.1.tar.gz
```

cd back to the nginx source root dir and configure, make and make install. Make sure you change the Nginx user on the configuration stage to one that suits your needs (--user=nginx --group=nginx):

```
cd /usr/src/nginx-1.7.6

./configure --add-module=/usr/src/nginx-1.7.6/ngx_pagespeed-1.9.32.1-beta --prefix=/usr/local/nginx --sbin-path=/usr/local/sbin/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --pid-path=/run/nginx.pid --lock-path=/run/lock/subsys/nginx --user=nginx --group=nginx
```

When configure stage is done :

```
sudo make

sudo make install
```

That will get you the last Nginx version with the last pagespeed mod and libraries ready to rock.

Comment: Hi, I know this is a very old thread, but I have a question, I have followed your guide to install nginx version 1.10.2. So I would like to know, do I need to load modules    " include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;"  in "etc/nginx/nginx.conf" or it's automatically loaded with your method of configuration?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom PPA source to install nginx build with Pagespeed to your system.

Look at https://launchpad.net/~sandyd/+archive/nginx-current-pagespeed for the custom build.

Comment: That PPA no longer works.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this requires a number of commands execute if you **don't want to build NGINX from scratch.** Here is the bash script I'm using for [automatic installation of PageSpeed to an already-running NGINX instance](https://www.majlovesreg.one/adding-pagespeed-to-a-running-nginx-instance):

```
#!/bin/bash
# https://www.majlovesreg.one/tag/code/
# https://www.majlovesreg.one/adding-pagespeed-to-a-running-nginx-instance

# For custom NGINX version, use:
# ngver=1.14.2
# For passing via the command line, use:
# ngver=$1
# For automated detection of installed NGINX, use:
ngver=$(nginx -v 2>&1 | grep -oP '(?<=/).*')

moddir=/usr/share/nginx/modules
builddir=$(mktemp -d)

# Build in tmp directory
cd ${builddir}

# Use script provided by pagespeed
nice -n 19 ionice -c 3 bash <(curl -f -L -sS https://ngxpagespeed.com/install) -n ${ngver} -m -b ${builddir} -a '--with-compat' -y || { echo '!! error with module creation, exiting...'; exit 1; }

# Replace ngx_pagespeed.so if exists, otherwise, copy it
[ -f ${moddir}/ngx_pagespeed.so ] && sudo mv ${moddir}/ngx_pagespeed.so ${moddir}/ngx_pagespeed.so.old
sudo chmod 644 /usr/local/nginx/modules/ngx_pagespeed.so || { echo '!! error with module path, exiting...'; exit 2; }
sudo cp /usr/local/nginx/modules/ngx_pagespeed.so ${moddir}/

# If new module works well, clean up build and install files
sudo nginx -t && { sudo rm -r /usr/local/nginx; rm -r ${builddir}/incubator-pagespeed-ngx-latest-stable; rm -r ${builddir}/nginx-${ngver}; } || { echo '!! nginx conf failed, exiting...'; exit 4; }

# Restart NGINX
systemctl is-active nginx && sudo systemctl restart nginx || sudo systemctl start nginx
echo
systemctl --no-pager status nginx
echo
echo 'Build and install of ngx_pagespeed sucessful!'
echo
```

To enable the dynamic module and to set other PageSpeed settings, see: https://www.majlovesreg.one/adding-pagespeed-to-a-running-nginx-instance