# Installing ngx_pagespeed with nginx 1.6.2 (Backport) on debian 7 (wheezy)

Tags: nginx, debian, debian-wheezy, mod-pagespeed, page-speed

I am struggling to install nginx 1.6.2 with module ngx_pagespeed 1.9.32.1-beta

Can anyone please help me to install this on my debian 7.

Any working tutorial i have tried

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-ngx_pagespeed-module-to-nginx-in-debian-wheezy

[Adding PageSpeed Module to installed nginx](https://serverfault.com/questions/605056/adding-pagespeed-module-to-installed-nginx/637116#637116?newreg=d020d9a87b4f40f18b274f2a933ad5cf)

but no luck.

Please help

Comment: What problems do you have exactly?

Comment: sometimes it doesn't take the pagespeed module and sometime i get error while building the custom pkg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of manually compiling Nginx with pagespeed, it will be a lot easier to use the precompiled package from Dotdeb Repo. This is how you can easily do this:

1) Add [dotdeb Repo](http://www.dotdeb.org/instructions/) to your sources list

2) Add the GPG key

3) Update and Upgrade `apt-get`

4) Install Nginx with pagespeed compiled package like this (this will install both nginx, pagespeed and many other modules with it):

```
sudo aptitude install nginx-extras
```

5) Add your Nginx Configurations to `nginx.conf` and VHost files

6) Configure Pagespeed and add them to the VHost files

7) Create Symbolic Link of VHost Configuration file in sites-enabled folder

8) Reload Nginx

That's pretty much it. Since you are using Debian 7 it is much simpler installing `nginx-extras` package from [DotDeb](http://www.dotdeb.org/) repo as it has many modules compiled together already and its just a 1 step installation to install them all. Dotdeb also have the latest versions available in their repo.

Comment: will you please give me full steps beacause i am so exhaused to try something on my own.

Please give me the full working steps that will be the help of billions for me..

Comment: and i dont want any other 3rd party packages except ngx_pagespeed

Comment: I've already given you step by step instructions. You have to put in an effort first going through the above steps and then ask questions with more info on what and where you are having problem with. Your question is too vague now...

Comment: sry bro u have explained it very clearly i appreciate that but i think nginx-extras is having many 3rd party modules included..

I dont want any other 3rd party module except ngx_pagespeed.. is it possible with dotdeb.?

Comment: I am actually building server for performance so i dont want things which are not useful for me.

Answer (score 0):

what is the issue that you're seeing when you try to compile ngx with pagespeed? any logs would be helpful.

also please see https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/build_ngx_pagespeed_from_source for build instructions.

Thanks,
Jeff